# Using just one design pattern in application

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm trying to learn how to make my application has the same "face" in all files, the same pattern, but I do not know if this is the right thing to do.

I want know if the more correct in software development, is to limit the application to only one type of pattern.

For example, that's how my application looks like (just a piece)

**Api.js:**

```
'use strict'
var Server = require('./server');
var Api = {
 init: function() {
   Server.init('start');
 }
};
```

**Server.js:**

```
'use strict'
var Server = {
 init: function(command) {
  this.command = command;

  if (command === 'start') {
    this.start();
  }
 }
};
```

I'm using the "initializer object pattern" in all my application. So i'm avoiding decorator pattern, facade, everything.

Should i avoid or i can use more than one? If the right answer is use several, depending on the needs, i have other question. This doesn't make the maintenance more difficult? Is not make the code like a spaghetti?

Thanks.

---

Update.

I'm going to try explain again, this time with a bounty.

i already try to ask but seems that no one really can give me a concise answer.

I would like to know what are the secrets from making a good app, a good web app, talking about code appearance. I want know if I should maintain the same standard code throughout my hole application, if this is GOOD, or really doesn't matter.

For example, i have two **EXAMPLES** files

app.js:

```
var server = require('./server');

var app = {
 init: function() {
   server.init('DEVELOPMENT');
 }
};

module.exports = app;
```

server.js:

```
var server = {
 init: function(env) {
  if (env === 'DEVELOPMENT') {
    // CODE
  } else {
    // CODE
  }
 }
}

module.exports = server;
```

In this case, i'm using one object with method init, which is the pattern that i'm using in my hole app..

Or it doesn't matter, i should write anything:

first object:

```
var server = require('./server');

var app = {
 init: function() {
   server('DEVELOPMENT');
 }
};

module.exports = app;
```

than server as a function:

```
var server =function(env) {
  if (env === 'DEVELOPMENT') {
    // CODE
  } else {
    // CODE
  }
}

module.exports = server;
```

I can give 100 of my points. it's incredible how i can't find a good answer for this particular issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You use patterns to solve specific problems in software development.  If you only have one problem, then you'll only need one pattern.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your intention. I'm guessing that there will be only one Server module and many modules like Api. Is that true?

Comment: My intention would be use only the object initializer pattern in all application @RobertMoskal

Comment: The design-patterns you speak of generally only apply to statically-typed, (usually single-inheritance) class-based OOP languages like C++ and Java. JavaScript is none of those. I'm not saying none of them are applicable, but you seem dogmatic in your approach.

Comment: Use as many patterns as you like. Just keep it simple.

Comment: In JS i can use: factory, publisher/subscriber, strategy, observer, mediator, iterator, facade, decorator, adapter, composite, proxy, initializer, module. I would like to now if i can use everyone in my application your if i should stick with one @Dai

Comment: What about maintenance? How should i keep it simple? I already made several courses, but i can't find one about this subject.

Comment: What do you mean by having all the same files have the same face?

Comment: the same init process.. using just functions, using objects, using prototype, etc, etc

Comment: I think you are missing the point of design patterns. Patterns are common solutions to some problems that come up repeatedly; if you encounter a situation that matches an existing pattern, the pattern can be a useful and efficient way to solve the problem. Great software may use lots of patterns or very few; it really depends on the situation. Note that using lots of patterns without a good reason will make your code worse, not better.

Comment: Learning about the history of design patterns may also help. They were invented by Christopher Alexander, an architect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pattern_Language.

Comment: but what about common codes, should i stick one way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Should I using other patterns?**

No, you should not insist on a single pattern.

No [design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SEIBB8) [pattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) will ever advise you to use a single pattern.
Just like you cannot chop all ingredients in one single way (are you going to *dice* the spaghetti?), you cannot organise all logic in one single pattern.

Sure, you can make *all* your Objects use the initialiser pattern, and don't use constructors at all.
This is ok.  Been there, done that.  I like it.

But these objects can be used with [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) or [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) (if it make things [simpler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverowe/archive/2007/07/11/are-design-patterns-a-bad-idea.aspx)).
As long as the builders/factories themselves have initialiser, and that they properly initialise the created objects, then your use of the initialiser pattern will be consistent.
Outside of [creational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) patterns,
it is usually good to organise objects with [structural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern) and [behavioural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern) patterns.
They do not conflict with initialiser at all.

For example, look at [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).
All nodes are created by the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object - [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode), [comments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createComment), even [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent).
This is the [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.

Yet the Document object is *also* a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)!
From it you access the whole system's [status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState), [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets), you can even [write to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)!
Every DOM operation starts from the Document, it is the Facade of the DOM system.

DOM nodes also implements multiple patterns.
They are organised in [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), [let you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) listen to events with [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and [Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), and handle events in a [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).
They are certainly parsed by an [Interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern), [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) is a [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), svg elements are [implemented](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/svg/SVGLineElement.cpp) as [Decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), and [createNodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator) obviously gives you an [Iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern).

The point is, good object-oriented design will yield *multiple* design patterns as a *result*, intentional or not.

---

**What are the secrets for good code appearance**

I think the best looking code is the one that is easiest to understand *to you*,
and the way you read code [changes](http://synesthesiam.com/posts/modeling-how-programmers-read-code.html) as you gain more experience.

For example [my style](https://github.com/Sheep-y/ufoafterlight-db/blob/master/res/ui.builder.js) is too condensed for most programmers, but to me it strikes a good balance.
So do develop your own style - you are not me, and you are not yesterday's you either.

Remember this as we go through the [styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style).

At the lowest level we have **[coding style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)** - most importantly indent and bracket.

This one is simple, pick the one you like and stick with it.
There are [language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) [specific](https://css-tricks.com/css-style-guides/) [styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style), and they are often good starting points.
Configure your IDE's [formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/code-style-javascript.html) so that you can format all your code with hotkey.

Above the code syntax we have **[comment style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_%28computer_programming%29#Styles)** and **[naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29)**.

Setting [rules](https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#comments) on comment is fine, sometimes it is [necessary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style#General_C.2FC.2B.2B_Practices) for documenting tools.
Avoid [too](http://nealford.com/memeagora/2008/11/07/comments_are_a_code_smell.html) [much](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-without-comments/) [comment](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2013/04/14/what-makes-code-readable-not-what-you-think/) in practice.
You may also want to decide your [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript) and your stand on [naming](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/) function expressions.

Above these structures, we have **logic conventions**.

The same code logic can often be done in many ways, some more 'beautiful' than the others *in your eyes*.
Look at this [example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/nov06/pollice/).

I picked the second style on first sight: no [duplicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), logic is sectioned cleanly, format is not my style but reasonable.
But many programmers would prefer the first style: logic is plain as day, a [few duplications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28computer_programming%29) is worth it.
While abstract, this level is [quite deep](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1852332530) - present your logic the wrong way actually [increase the chance](http://synesthesiam.com/posts/what-makes-code-hard-to-understand.html) an *experienced* programmer read it wrong.

Finally, we arrives at the level of **design pattern**, about as far as code beauty goes.

The key to keep your code structure beautiful, is using the right patterns at right level to consistently accomplish [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) and [code reuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse),
while avoiding [pitfalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Software_engineering) and [over-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001120/what-is-over-engineering-as-applied-to-software).

[There](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449327680) [are](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1562764233) [quite](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) [some](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596510047) [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1312367660) [about](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596802293) beautiful code,
[and](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527349) [then](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) [there](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) [are](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073052337) [even](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136061699) [more](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201835959) [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540287132) [about](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652269X) designing and implementing beautiful software.
(Decide for yourself which are beyond your level.)
Knowledge is as important as experience, and you can gain them only by spending your time to study, to write, and to revise/refactor your apps.

Feel free to change your mind as you explore and experiment with your code.
Changing your mind is a good sign of learning.

But first, [familiarise yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315000/how-to-study-design-patterns) with design patterns.
Just don't forget, they are the generic *result* of applying [object-oriented principals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157847/learning-object-oriented-thinking) to common tasks.
It is still up to you to do the design.

Design Patterns [Are](http://blog.codinghorror.com/head-first-design-patterns/) [Not](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rethinking-design-patterns/) [Silver](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2009/03/19/why-following-design-patterns-is-a-bad-idea/) [Bullets](http://www.adamtornhill.com/articles/signs/signs.htm).

Comment: @AmandaFerrari Glad you liked it! Have my best wish on mastering programming styles. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the nature of this problem is one that will lend you to have a lot of open ended answers. Ultimately you'll need to choose the best aspects of existing paradigms and either work in full or in part with its methodologies. In my opinion, a lot of your API structure (and therefore design pattern) will come down to how you anticipate people accessing your endpoints for your application. Your proposed method of having a constructor object is a common and very flexible approach; it allows for prototyping for inevitable rewrites of the code and a easy to observe key and scope of the application. It you're ready to support EMCA6, switch this over to a `Class` based constructor and you'll find yourself having a very manageable code base that can grow, is object orientated and has a very accurate level of function scoping.

Typically, I have developed applications to follow this style of initalisation (trying to make it as human readable as possible):

```
var Application = {
    initialise: function (config) {
        config = config || {} // defaults;
        ....
        this.contactServer(config.serverConfiguration);

    },
    contactServer: function (configServer) {
        ....
    },
    renderServerPayload: function (payLoad) {}
};

Application.manageServerResponse = function (serverResponse) {
    this.renderServerPayload(serverResponse);
};
```

Good luck with your application. Hopefully this was somewhat useful.